# telnet accessing website with authentication

Tags: authentication, telnet

I am trying to access **httpbin.org** with basic authentication.
I must enter a username and a password.
Using telnet in the command terminal(linux) I execute at least :

```
telnet httpbin.org 80 
HEAD /basic-auth/user/passwd HTTP/1.1
```

It gives a 401 status code (unauthorized).

I want to now somehow access it using a username and a password (in Base64, entered as username:password). In what way do I do this? I've tried (after 401 status code)

```
HEAD /username:password HTTP/1.1
```

(but this gives a 404 status code)

Comment: You need to take the string of "username:password" and base64-encode it, and send that encoded string in a header: `Authorization Basic <base64-encoded-credentials>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HTTP Basic Authentication uses base-64 encoding of the username and password together.  For a username `testuser` and a password of `hunter2`, you would take the string `testuser:hunter2` and base64-encode that.  That will give you the string `dGVzdHVzZXI6aHVudGVyMg==`

How, you ask, do you get that encoding?  Most POSIX systems have `openssl` installed, in which case you can use the output of `echo -n "testuser:hunter2" | openssl base64 -base64`.  The `-n` is hyper-important, otherwise you'll also be including a `newline` in the encoding, which will give you an incorrect encoded string (as the password does not end with a newline character generally).

You can then transact via `telnet` thusly:

```
telnet hostname.example.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic dGVzdHVzZXI6aHVudGVyMg==
```

Comment: If you're not in a POSIX space, there's a Windows program available from Microsoft that will do base64 encoding/decoding:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/191239

Comment: Thank you, the base 64 converting worked well. I have a problem entering the password in the authorization header. Using your format `Authorization: Basic user:passwordinbase64` isn't working for me. When you access the website in a browser with the URL `httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd`, it requests a username and password, but URL `httpbin.org` doesn't. Using telnet, how and where do I enter the username and password spefically, so I can get access to page in my command line where I would get access to in a web browser?

Comment: (User) and : and (password) all get base64-encoded; that encoded result goes in the Authorization line.